# Can't print double matrix

Tags: java

I am essentially trying to print this double array in the main method. 
Everytime I pass through a (row, column) via the main method, it does not work. I am basically trying to write a larger code that creates a double matrix
and does a lot more stuff with it. This is just sort of the basic though. I would really appreciate any type of help I can get. I tried to do the Arrays.deepToString(); but that did not work either. Note that whenever the program is ran, it doesn't print anything. Thanks !

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class matrix{
     int row;   
    int column;
    int [][] matrix;

    matrix(int r, int c){
        r = row;
        c = column;
        matrix = new int [r][c];
        int[][] matrix = new int[row][column];
        for(int i = 0; i< matrix.length; i++){      
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){          
                matrix[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*21) - 10;
                System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }                   
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
r = row;
c = column;
```

to

```
this.row = r; // <-- this is optional, but would have prevented your error.
this.column = c;
```

As is you are changing your arguments (not your fields). Another way of providing some guard against modifying the arguments is to make them `final` - like

```
matrix(final int r, final int c)
```

Finally, and unrelated to your question, the usual Java naming conventions would have the class `matrix` as `Matrix`. And, you might use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) after your loop to `print` like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

#### Putting it all together

```
public class Matrix {
    int row;
    int column;
    int[][] matrix;

    Matrix(final int r, final int c) {
        this.row = r;
        this.column = c;
        this.matrix = new int[row][column];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 21) - 10;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, but how do i get it to print like an actual matrix though ? because  when i try to do the arrays.deepToString() outside the for loop, it still prints nothing.

Comment: @PranayPatel See edit. Your `int[][] matrix = new int[][];` line in the constructor creates a [*shadow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Comment: ok thank you so much for the feedback lol !! Just started learning java. got into oop last week, and it is deff a lil bit different ! thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

I think you only want to print a new line after each row in the matrix:

```
for (int i=0; i< matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*21) - 10;
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);

    }
    System.out.println();  // go to next row
}
```

As @Elliott pointed out, you also seem to have a problem in the code with how you are even initializing the matrix.  The full constructor might go something like this:

```
public Matrix(int r, int c) {
    this.row = r;
    this.column = c;
    matrix = new int[r][c];

    for (int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*21) - 10;
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println();  // go to next row
    }
}
```

Comment: To make your code cross-platform, use `System.out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` or more conveniently `System.out.println();`